# Optimizing the speed of a web scraper

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have just written this code to scrape some data from a website. In its current state it works fine, however, going by my tests on the script, I discovered that with the amount of data I am processing, it will take a few days to finish the task, Is there a way to improve its performance? I will insert a sample of the data as the bulk of it.

Input data in CSV format:

```
Code    Origin
1       Eisenstadt
2       Tirana
3       St Pölten Hbf
6       Wien Westbahnhof
7       Wien Hauptbahnhof
8       Klagenfurt Hbf
9       Villach Hbf
11      Graz Hbf
12      Liezen
```

Code:

```
# import needed libraries
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def datareader(datafile):

    """ This function reads the cities from csv file and processes

        them into an O-D for input into the web scrapper """


    # Read the csv
    with open(datafile, 'r') as f:

        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = reader.next()
        ListOfCities = [lines for lines in reader]
        temp = ListOfCities[:]

        city_num = []
        city_orig_dest = []
        for i in ListOfCities:
            for j in temp:
                ans1 = i[0], j[0]

                if ans1[0] != ans1[1]:
                    city_num.append(ans1)

                ans = (unicode(i[1], 'iso-8859-1'), unicode(j[1], 'iso-8859-1'),i[0], j[0])
                if ans[0] != ans[1] and ans[2] != ans[3]:
                    city_orig_dest.append(ans)

    yield city_orig_dest

input_data = datareader('BAK.csv') # Input data here


def webscrapper(x):

    """ This function scraped the required website and extracts the

        quickest connection time within given time durations """

    #Create a browser object
    br = Browser()

    # Ignore robots.txt
    br.set_handle_robots(False)

    # Google demands a user-agent that isn't a robot
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

    # Retrieve the Google home page, saving the response
    br.open('http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/query.exe/en')

    # Select the 6th form
    br.select_form(nr=6)

    # Assign origin and destination to the o d variables
    o = i[0].encode('iso-8859-1')
    d = i[1].encode('iso-8859-1')
    print 'o-d:', i[0], i[1]

    # Enter the text input (This section should be automated to read multiple text input as shown in the question)
    br.form["REQ0JourneyStopsS0G"] = o  # Origin train station (From)
    br.form["REQ0JourneyStopsZ0G"] = d  # Destination train station (To)
    br.form["REQ0JourneyTime"] = x  # Search Time
    br.form["date"] = '18.01.17'  # Search Date

    # Get the search results
    br.submit()


    #Click the later link three times to get trip times
    for _ in xrange(5):

        # Looking at some results in link format

        for l in br.links(text='Later'):

            pass
            response = br.follow_link(l)

        # get the response from mechanize Browser
        soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(), 'lxml', from_encoding="utf-8")
        trs = soup.select('table.hfs_overview tr')

        connections_times = []
        ListOfSearchTimes = []
        # Scrape the search results from the resulting table
        for tr in trs:
            locations = tr.select('td.location')
            if len(locations) > 0:
                time = tr.select('td.time')[0].contents[0].strip()
                ListOfSearchTimes.append(time.encode('latin-1'))
                durations = tr.select('td.duration')

                # Check that the duration cell is not empty
                if len(durations) == 0:
                    duration = ''
                else:
                    duration = durations[0].contents[0].strip()

                    # Convert duration time string to minutes
                    def get_sec(time_str):
                        h, m = time_str.split(':')
                        return int(h) * 60 + int(m)

                    connections_times.append(get_sec(duration))


    def group(lst, n):
        return zip(*[lst[i::n] for i in range(n)])

    arrivals_and_departure_pair = group(ListOfSearchTimes, 2)


    #Check that the selected departures for one interval occurs before the departure of the next interval
    fmt = '%H:%M'
    finalDepartureList = []

    for ind, res in arrivals_and_departure_pair:

        t1 = datetime.strptime(ind, fmt)

        if x == '05:30':

            control = datetime.strptime('09:00', fmt)

        if x == '09:00':
            control = datetime.strptime('12:00', fmt)

        if x == '12:00':
            control = datetime.strptime('15:00', fmt)

        if x == '15:00':
            control = datetime.strptime('18:00', fmt)

        if x == '18:00':
            control = datetime.strptime('21:00', fmt)

        if x == '21:00':
            control = datetime.strptime('05:30', fmt)

        if t1 < control:

            finalDepartureList.append(ind)


    # Get the the list of connection times for the departures above
    fastest_connect = connections_times[:len(finalDepartureList)]


    #Get the fastest connections time and catch any error when there is no connection between the OD pairs
    try:
        best_connect = sorted(fastest_connect)[0]
        print 'fastest connection', best_connect
        # print duration
    except IndexError:
        print "No Connection"
        #print

    #Return the result of the search
    if len(fastest_connect) == 0:
        return [i[2], i[3], '999999']
    else:
        return [i[2], i[3], str(best_connect)]



# List of time intervals
times = ['05:30', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']


# Write the heading of the output text file
headings = ["from_BAKCode", "to_BAKCode", "interval", "duration"]
f = open("traveltime_rail2rail_2017.txt", "w+")
f.write(','.join(headings))
f.write('\n')
f.close()


# Call the web scraper function

for i in input_data.next():

    for index, time in enumerate(times):

        result = webscrapper(time)

        result.insert(2, str(index+1))

        print 'result:', result
        print

        f = open("traveltime_rail2rail_2017.txt", "a")
        f.write(','.join(result[0:4]))
        f.write('\n')
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Performance Issues

The main bottleneck here is the **blocking nature of the program**. You are processing urls one by one sequentially - you don't process the next url until you are done with the current one. This can be solved by switching to an asynchronous approach - either using [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) (which is the best thing happened in the Python's web-scraping world), or something like [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

Also, the HTML parsing speed can be improved by *parsing only the relevant part of the document* with a [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


parse_only = SoupStrainer("table", class_="hfs_overview")
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response(), 'lxml', from_encoding="utf-8", parse_only=parse_only)

trs = soup.select('tr')
```

The other thing you can try is to switch from `mechanize` to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) using a single [`requests.Session()` instance](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) for all the requests. This way, *the underlying TCP connection will be reused* which may result into a performance improvement.

There are also some things you are re-doing over and over again in the loops. Things like the `control` variable should be *pre-computed* beforehand.

And, avoid redefining the `get_sec()` function inside the loop - defined it beforehand.

Also, use [`min()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) instead of calling `sorted()` and getting the first element.

---

#### Code Style Issues

- `if len(locations) > 0:` can be improved as `if locations:`
- `if len(durations) == 0:` can be improved as `if not durations:`
- `if len(fastest_connect) == 0:` can be improved as `if not fastest_connect:`
- `.select(..)[0]` can be replaced with `.select_one(...)`
- `BeautifulSoup` understands *file-like objects* as well, replace `br.response().read()` with `br.response()`
- organize imports as per [PEP8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id23):

  ```
  import csv
  from datetime import datetime

  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from mechanize import Browser
  ```
- the `# import needed libraries` comment does not make much sense
- no need for the extra newline before the function docstrings
- put the main program logic into [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid it being executed on import
- by introducing the `time` variable, you are *shadowing* the imported `time` module
- [properly define constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id47) (for example, the time format, or the magical `999999` number)
- use [`with` context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) when dealing with files
- remove the unused `header` variable
- [skip the CSV header via the `next()` built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257373/skip-the-headers-when-editing-a-csv-file-using-python): `next(reader, None)`

---

#### A note about Python 3 compatibility:

- [use `next()` function instead of the `.next()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414210/python-why-should-i-use-next-and-not-obj-next)
- `range()` vs `xrange()` ([cross-Python way to handle both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015199/771848))
- use `print()` function instead of a statement

---

Here is a sample code that uses `requests` to make a search (note that we handle the default parameters "manually" - if you want to automatically handle the default parameter values as in case of `mechanize`, look into [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) or [`RoboBrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser)):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    """Given two dicts, merge them into a new dict as a shallow copy."""
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z


url = "http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/query.exe/en"
DEFAULT_PARAMS = {
    "changeQueryInputData=yes&start": "Search connection",

    "REQ0Total_KissRideMotorClass": "404",
    "REQ0Total_KissRideCarClass": "5",
    "REQ0Total_KissRide_maxDist": "10000000",
    "REQ0Total_KissRide_minDist": "0",
    "REQComparisonCarload": "0",

    "REQ0JourneyStopsS0A": "255",
    "REQ0JourneyStopsZ0A": "255",
    "REQ0JourneyStops1.0G": "",
    "REQ0JourneyStops1.0A": "1",
    "REQ0JourneyStopover1": ""
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"}

    session.get(url)  # visit the main page (might not be actually needed)

    # sample parameters
    params = {
        "REQ0JourneyStopsS0G": "Eisenstadt",
        "REQ0JourneyStopsZ0G": "Tirano, Stazione",
        "date": "27.02.17",
        "REQ0JourneyTime": "17:00"
    }
    response = session.post(url, data=merge_two_dicts(DEFAULT_PARAMS, params))

    parse_only = SoupStrainer("table", class_="hfs_overview")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml", parse_only=parse_only)

    # print out times for demonstration purposes
    trs = soup.select('tr')
    for tr in trs:
        time = tr.select_one('td.time')
        if time:
            print(time.get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. can you write a line of code showing how the requests can be used in the code.

Comment: @Nobi yup, good idea, I was thinking about that, will do, thanks.

Comment: with your suggestions, there is definitely a significant improvement (10secs saved on each iteration) which will lead to considerable time saving since I have a lot of iterations to deal with. Also, very helpful tips for my future programming efforts.

Comment: @Nobi awesome! Glad to see it is helping. I've included a sample `requests` code (please try it out and measure if it is faster than mechanize). Thanks.

Comment: I know this is coming very late, but are you able to show me any other scheme to further increase the speed of this code. context: After your good work, one iteration now runs in about 4secs and I have just over 1million iterations to run, that will take over 40days, that's a lot of time which I dont have. Please help

Comment: @Nobi no problem. Well, next idea, would be to scale it up to multiple machines - having multiple instances of your script running against a subset of input data - sort of a divide and conquer approach - divide the work into parts and let each of the instances of your script handle a separate part. Then, merge the results in a, say, database. That said, you may be hitting the site even more hard this way - make sure, you are on the legal side of things and do not violate the terms of use - be a good web-scraping citizen. Thanks.

Comment: @Nobi or, you can try to put the latest version of your code to a new question here on code review for an another round..

Comment: I have posted the latest version, kindly go through it. Thanks  too for your response and advice. Indeed I have double checked the site's terms of use.

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the beginning:

```
import threading as th

class scrape(th.Thread()):
    def __init___(self, time):
        self.time = time
    def run(self):
        return webscrapper(self.time)
```

And this instead of the for loop at the end:

```
for i in input_data.next():

    for index, time in enumerate(times):

        result = scrape(time)

        result = result.start()

        result.insert(2, str(index+1))

        print 'result:', result
        print

    f = open("traveltime_rail2rail_2017.txt", "a")
    f.write(','.join(result[0:4]))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review! Please see: [How do I write a good answer?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), where you will find: "Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted".